# installing Ubuntu and replacing Windows

Tags: system-installation, windows-7

How can I install Ubuntu and replace Windows without a flash drive or burning a CD?

Can I use an external hard drive?

If so, what would be the procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dustin, you do need a flash drive or DVD/CD if you want that, and it is definitely a worthy investment and these days isn't expensive at all. Even after installing Ubuntu and replacing Windows 7 with Ubu (good decision from your part!), you always have a Live image to boot your PC,if anything would happen, or other PCs with to show others without installing, or write future releases of Ubuntu onto the medium!

Comment: I ended up finding a flash drive and installing with that method.

Answer (score 1):

I'd get a flashdrive, seeing there's no other options, than those two (As far as I know).

A flashdrive of the right size, is only a few bucks. And taking into consideration that Ubuntu is free. I'd get one, and install Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu on top of Windows using the following procedure:

1. Download the WUBI installer (from link below).  This will setup Ubuntu on a different partition and allow you to boot into Ubuntu.
2. You can uninstall Ubuntu like you would any other Windows Program.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Comment: I have Ubuntu installed this way but want to replace Windows with Ubuntu solely.  I don't have blank CDs nor a flash drive.  My roommates don't have those either.  I think it would be a waste to buy a flash drive or CD for only one purpose; therefore, I am trying to find a work around to remove Windows 7 for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Wubi from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

This installs ubuntu inside windows and then migrate wubi to a partition instructions  in link below

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi

Answer (score 0):

remember to restore the grub for ubuntu , other wise it may cause some problem during boot up of the ubuntu u install 
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd